# How do I display the submitted data in the same page?

Tags: 7, forms

I created a custom form in Drupal 7. I need to display the submitted data in the same page showing the form, without using `drupal_set_message()`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$form_state['rebuild']`;

If `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` has been set then a new copy of the form is immediately built and sent to the browser. Instead of a redirect to new page.

Example:

```
function example_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
  // we return the submitted value to the form
  // by storing it in $form_state['storage'] and rebuilding
  $form_state['storage']['some_value'] = $form_state['values']['some_value'];
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

You can refer https://www.drupal.org/node/2171993

Another way store the "`$form_state['values']`" in session.

Take @clive answer [How to display an HTML table after the form submission on the same page as the form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30243/how-to-display-an-html-table-after-the-form-submission-on-the-same-page-as-the-f) as reference.